# Problem publish Avro event to kafka from spring cloud stream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, avro, spring-cloud-stream

I have spring cloud stream app that process kafka stream with aggregation.
after aggregation I call Kafka stream to method to publish the result to a new topic.

When I use JsonSerializer it works fine but when I use Avro with local schema registry I get the following :

> org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Error encountered sending record to topic eyali.target for task 1_0 due to:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: You must configure() before serialize() or use serializer constructor with SchemaRegistryClient
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:177) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:139) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:85) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:253) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:232) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:191) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
> at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:42) ~[kafka-streams-3.0.0.jar:na]
> .....
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: You must configure() before serialize() or use serializer constructor with SchemaRegistryClient

After the aggregation is done I use native KafkaStream to publish to a topic (via to method)

```
.to(targetTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.Long(), new SpecificAvroSerde<>()));
```

In my application.properties I use the following:

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

Comment: My hunch would be to look through the startup logs (they should display the config used for kafka clients) and ensure your producers/consumers have been injected with the `schema.registry.url` you provided

Comment: thanx. what should I look for?